# c++ I am get always same number Radnom between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, matrix, random, codeblocks, random-seed

```
double Matrix::getRandomNumber()
{
    double r;

    srand(time(NULL));
    r = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;

    return r;
}
```

I am always get same number.

and I tried this way:

```
double Matrix::getRandomNumber()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0,1);

    return dist(gen);
}
```

I am still get same Number.
I am using code blocks.
and c++14.

when I did this:

```
void Matrix::printToConsole()
{
    for(int y = 0; y<this->Cols; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<this->Rows; x++)
        {
            std::cout<<this->getRandomNumber()<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

it is my result on console:

```
0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082
0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082
0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082
0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082
0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082 0.518082
```

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` only once in your program at startup.

Comment: Each time you call `Matrix::getRandomNumber()`, you're creating a new instance of `std::random_device`. Make it static (`static std::random_device rd;`) or global, or otherwise persistant, e.g. by making it a static member of `Matrix`..

Comment: I make it static. And that worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714)

Comment: But I get some numbers that is not between 0 and 1. I get this nums:              0.297901 0.563295 1.95833e-306
0.35442 0.318691 3.95576e-270

Comment: Perhaps you want to look up floating point arithmetic.

Comment: all those numbers are between 0 and 1. `1.95833e-306`  is 0.000......00019583